# In JCheckBoxMenuItem, how to make only the checkbox tickmark visible

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

[image]

In this image taken from eclipse, "Build Automatically" shows a tick mark without a checkbox. How can I create a similar effect to this with Java JCheckBoxMenuItems, where only the tickmark and not the checkbox are visible?

Comment: Note: Eclipse isn't built with Swing, so it's not immediately translatable.

Comment: @skaffman: what graphic library has been used to write eclipse?

Comment: @0verbose: SWT (http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)

Comment: don't invent visually inconsistent ui - the appearance of the menu is controlled by the LAF and (usually) what the user is accustomed to.

Answer (score 2):

The appearance is defined by [`BasicMenuItemUI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicMenuItemUI.html), typically unique to each Look & Feel. You can supply your own variation that overrides `paintMenuItem()`. As doing so will violate the user's preferred Look & Feel, you'll have to decide if it's worth the effort.

Addendum: @camickr's `Icon` idea is more elegant, but you can always put a [✔ (U+2714)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2714/index.htm) in the menu's text.

Comment: or JToggleButton with Icon +1

Comment: never a good idea to subclass an ui-delegate (too much work with questionable outcome). Even if you do, you would have to target on a concrete laf (not basicXX). Doubt that the unicode mark would appear properly aligned .. the menu layout can barely handle icons

Comment: @kleopatra: Your are right on both counts. Possibly, a rendering of the glyph might make a nice icon.

Answer (score 2):

JCheckBoxMenuItem extends from AbstractButton so you should be able to provide custom Icons for the appropriate set???Icon methods.

Comment: As an aside, `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel` actually uses ✔ in the UI default for `CheckBoxMenuItem.checkIcon`.

Comment: @mKorbel, whats with all the "by anonymous up-voter" comments? If you upvote then make a comment explaining why (if you wish). If you don't upvote then there is no need for a comment like that.

Comment: @camickr if it's annoying, could change that with some another empty words, that my respect in cases wheh all the words are useless, I'm who I'm, maybe my wrong decision ..., and not for all poster in this forum :-)

Comment: I tried this without success. I called all of `setIcon`, `setSelectedIcon`, `setDisabledIcon`, `setDisabledSelectedIcon`, `setPressedIcon`, `setRolloverIcon` and `setRolloverSelectedIcon` on a `JCheckBoxMenuItem` to set a blank icon, but it has no effect on the LaF's default painting of a checkbox and/or tick mark beside the menu item.

Answer (score -1):

you can extend JCheckbox and override paintComponent()

Comment: -1, What does a JTextField have to do with a JCheckBoxMenuItem? You wouldn't use a text field for this, components added to a menu has special functionality, that is why you don't just use a JCheckBox.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with JMenuItem and an ActionListener:

```
JMenuItem jcmi1 = new JMenuItem("   Choix 1");

jcmi1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (jcmi1.getText()!="\u2714  Choix 1"){
                jcmi1.setText("\u2714  Choix 1");
            }else{
                jcmi1.setText("   Choix 1");
            }
        }

    });
```